# Pine editor Stoploss or TakeProfit if only there is a Long Position

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying an easy breakout system for shorter time periods such as 1m, 5m, 15.
When the high price crosses over the last fractal's high, this is a Long Entry signal.
Then if the high crosses over 0.1% of high price this is Take Profit.
But if the low crosses under 0.1% of high price this is Stop Loss.

The below code puts Long Entry and closes the position e.g. Stop Loss. But I can not control if there is any open Long Entry position. It should check if the last Long Entry is closed with either Stop Loss or Take Profit. So as you can see, it also puts Stop Loss even there is no open Long Entry. I tried with the barssince() function but no luck.

Thank you in advance.

```
//@version=4
study("Williams Fractals Breakout",shorttitle="Fractals", overlay=true)

// Define "n" as the number of periods and keep a minimum value of 2 for error handling.
n = input(title="Periods", defval=2, minval=2)


topFractal = (high[n-2] < high[n]) and (high[n-1] < high[n]) and (high[n+1] < high[n]) and (high[n+2] < high[n]) //dnFractal
bottomFractal = (low[n-2] > low[n]) and (low[n-1] > low[n]) and (low[n+1] > low[n]) and (low[n+2] > low[n])


// Plot the fractals as shapes on the chart.
plotshape(topFractal, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.abovebar, offset=-2, color=color.green, transp=0)
plotshape(bottomFractal, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.belowbar, offset=-2, color=color.red, transp=0)  


enterLong_p = valuewhen(topFractal, high[n], 0)
exitLongTP_p = valuewhen(topFractal, enterLong_p * 1.001, 0)
exitLongSL_p = valuewhen(topFractal, enterLong_p * (1-0.001), 0)
enterLong= high == enterLong_p or crossover(high, enterLong_p)
exitLongTP= high == exitLongTP_p or crossover(high, exitLongTP_p)
exitLongSL= low == exitLongSL_p or crossunder(low, exitLongSL_p)
O1= barssince(enterLong)
O2= barssince(exitLongTP)
O3= barssince(exitLongSL)

    
plotshape(enterLong and O3<O1[1] ? high : na, title="enterLong", text="Long Entry", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
//plotshape(exitLongTP and (O3<O1[1] or O1<O2[1]) ? high+1 : na, title="exitLongTP", text="Exit Long TP", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.blue, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
plotshape(exitLongSL and O1<O3[1] ? high+2 : na, title="exitLongSL", text="Exit Long SL", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strategy` is more suitable then `study` for your task:

```
//@version=4
strategy("Williams Fractals Breakout",shorttitle="Fractals", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

n = input(title="Periods", defval=2, minval=2)
topFractal = (high[n-2] < high[n]) and (high[n-1] < high[n]) and (high[n+1] < high[n]) and (high[n+2] < high[n]) //dnFractal
bottomFractal = (low[n-2] > low[n]) and (low[n-1] > low[n]) and (low[n+1] > low[n]) and (low[n+2] > low[n])


// Plot the fractals as shapes on the chart.
plotshape(topFractal, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.abovebar, offset=-2, color=color.green, transp=0)
plotshape(bottomFractal, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.belowbar, offset=-2, color=color.red, transp=0)  

enterLong_p = valuewhen(topFractal, high[n], 0)

// added strategy logic here
strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, stop = enterLong_p)
percentAsPoints(pcnt) =>
    strategy.position_size != 0 ? round(pcnt / 100 * strategy.position_avg_price / syminfo.mintick) : float(na)
strategy.exit("x", loss = percentAsPoints(0.1), profit = percentAsPoints(0.1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Maybe changing it to strategy is more logical as you suggested. However, when a position is exited either with Stop Loss or Take Profit I would like to wait for the new fractal. This strategy and my study does not wait for the new one. Should I change the value to 0 of enterLong_p after strategy.entry?

Comment: You can add `when` parameter for `strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, stop = enterLong_p)` with appropriate condition for entry.